# How to implement variance and standard deviation in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Is it possible to do standard deviation in pymongo aggregation framework? I am not able to find any atomic operation like $avg, $sum, $min, $max.

My only other two possibilities are

1. go through the rows and calculate it in python
2. Use map reduce.

I could easily write this in python but I think it is a bad idea as I will be compromising on performance. And map reduce seems to be a really hard thing to lean. I am not able to understand what map and reduce really mean at this point.

Before I begin digesting map reduce, I thought to ask Stackoverflow community if there is something that is readily available so that I do not end up reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the upcoming 3.2 version of Mongo. They add a couple of new aggregation methods, one of them is [standard deviation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#grp._S_stdDevSamp).

Answer (score 1):

$avg, $sum, $min, $max are all supported as part of a $group in the pipeline. See here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_group